# Swift function that return two strings fail when its in loop

Tags: ios, swift

I Wrote a function that return two Strings, when calling the function regularly its works fine, but when I'm running the function through loop, I'm getting this error:

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0xbfffcba0)

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    test()
}

func test()
{
    var funcs = [checkButton]
    var a = checkButton(value: 1) // Runs OK
    for f in funcs{
        var result = f(value: 1) // Fail
    }
}

func checkButton(#value: Int) -> (location: String, pattern: String){
    return ("abc","cba")
}
```

**Update:**

I'm using Xcode 6 beta 2, and running Mavericks on VMware Workstation.

Also, I've just created new clean project with that code and still getting the error.

Comment: there is no problem with this code at all. runs like a charm on my computer.

Comment: How can it be? I'm running Xcode version 6.0 (6A215I), same as you?

Comment: mine is Xcode 6.0 (6A216f), briefly the _beta-2_. you are using the _beta-1_.

Comment: So I've updated the Xcode, and still getting the same error with different address: 0xbfffcbb0.

Comment: It works fine for me on beta 1 (6A215l)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that it doesn't work for me either. Created a iOS single-view app from template, and added above code. crash. As an experiment, I took it out of the array (just `f = self.checkButton`) and got the same result.

I think it's a bug in the compiler.

First according to the book, a method is actually a function which is actually a closure, albeit one with special properties and restrictions. Shouldn't `self.checkButton` (or implicit version) be sufficient to "give it an existing instance", making it a closure? If MattL is correct that instance methods can't be used as closures, then the compiler shouldn't allow you to assign one to anything.

Second, the crash occurs on the exit, not on the call. And if you reference `self` in `checkButton`, (e.g. `println(self.title)` having previously set title), it works fine. That suggests that the instance is indeed known and operating, just something wrong on the return.

Third, changing it to a class method doesn't help. Changing these lines

```
  var a = ViewController.checkButton(value: 1) 
  var funcs = [ViewController.checkButton]

  class func checkButton(#value: Int) -> (location: String, pattern: String)
```

results in the same crash. I don't see any similar prohibition on context for class methods.

Fourth, if you simply change the return type from `(location: String, pattern: String)` to just `String` and return `abc`, then the whole thing works fine.

Fourth, if you wrap `test` and `checkButton` in a new class `testClass`, and then call it as below, it works:

```
    class testClass {

    func test()
    {
        var funcs = [checkButton]
        var a = checkButton(value: 1) // Runs OK
        for f in funcs {
            var result = f(value: 1) // Fail
            println(result)
        }
    }

    func checkButton(#value: Int) -> (location: String, pattern: String){
        return ("abc","cba")
    }

}


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let g = testClass()
        g.test()
    }


}
```

Now change testClass to testClass: NSObject and it crashes.

So it looks like the compiler is botching up a method return when called as a closure with a tuple in a Obj-C subclass. When I put it like that, I must say that it's not terribly surprising nobody's noticed yet; you're really pushing the edge here!

---

More practically, in the meantime, if it's helpful, an alternative to changing your method to a closure is to keep it unchanged and just wrap it as you put it in the array:

```
 var funcs = [{value in self.checkButton(value: value)}]
```

This seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>This code runs fine for me. Your `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` must be coming from some other part of your code. Try setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code to find the line throwing the error.</strike>

From the “The Swift Programming Language.”

`“An instance method can be called only on a specific instance of the type it belongs to. It cannot be called in isolation without an existing instance.”`

`checkButton()` is an instance method, not a closure. It works in the first case because there is an implicit `self.` before `checkButton()`. It will not work in the second case.

If you want to make checkButton a closure you could declare it like so:

```
let checkButton = { (#value: Int) -> (location: String, pattern: String) in
    return ("abc","cba")
}
```

Comment: When skipping this line its works fine. I have tried it many times, re-write that again and again, but nothing, still getting the error.

Comment: Can you edit your question to display the whole file and your call to the `test()` method?

Comment: So how can it be that its working fine for everyone but me? And also, how can I make it work? Thanks.

Comment: It was working fine for us because you only gave the `test` and `checkButton` methods without their context. I'm not sure what your end goal is but I'll update my answer again with a way to make it work.